# Creating a private command within a LaTeX class

Tags: document-classes

I am currently creating a new LaTeX class for my university. It has commands like \printTitle for rendering the title page that the writers call from their own .tex document.

However, there are a number of internal methods within the class like \def\renderTitlePage{} that I would like to be private so they cannot be called directly by the authors. Does anyone know how to make a class method private? At present, I can see the command \renderTitlePage in texStudio and Overleaf while I am editing a chapter.

Comment: This is not possible (to the best of my knowledge), any command can be redefined, I think this is even true within latex3 although someone more authoritative would be best placed to answer properly

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. TeX doesn't really have private namespaces, but internal commands can be removed from simple user modification by including @ in their names. See [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351). Or if you're using Expl3 syntax, _ and : are part of the programmer namespace, but not the user namespace.

Comment: By "private" here I think you mean that editors like TexStudio and Overleaf doesn't pick up on those commands as suggestions to the end user. If this is true, your request might be off-topic here. Regardless, you could consider `\newcommand{\mynewcommand}{\newcommand}` (similarly `\def\mydef{\def}`) and then use `\mynewcommand` (`\mydef`) to define new commands everywhere.

Comment: the usual convention is to use names with `@`  so they can not be called from normal document  markup,  and use a common unique prefix  so you dont clash with other packages `\Dowdeswell@renderTitlePage` ,  `\Dowdeswell@abc`, ...

Comment: Thank you JamesT, Alan, Werner, and David. All of those suggestions are worth investigating. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just a note about Overleaf: in my experience it doesn't autocomplete any commands within a class or package unless it already knows about it. So if all you commands are in a `.cls` or `.sty` file, Overleaf won't find them anyway.  It's still good practice to follow the naming conventions @DavidCarlisle and I mention, but the Overleaf problem should be solved simply by putting your commands in a class or package rather than distributing them in the form e.g. of a user template.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual LaTeX2e convention is to use names with `@` so they can not be called from normal document markup, and use a common unique prefix so you dont clash with other packages `\Dowdeswell@renderTitlePage` , `\Dowdeswell@abc`.

If using L3 code it is similar but using `_` and a more formalised module system
`\dowdeswell_render_title_page:` with an optional possibility of registering the module prefixes so no one else uses the same prefix
https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/main/l3kernel/doc/l3prefixes.csv

Comment: Thank you David. I tried that this morning and it works perfectly. I appreciate your help.